# How not to break apt configuration when mixing package lists from different Debian releases

Tags: debian, apt, package-management

I do experiment with the latest Debian "testing" (Trixie) and figured out that I need some packages from "stable" (Bookworm).

Update: my use case is, that I have unmet dependency issue of Forticlient 7.2.2, specifically: libappindicator1

I had to combine package lists - so far so good. However I want to know if this can have cause hard-to-identify problems in the future.

This is my `sources.list`:

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ trixie main non-free-firmware contrib non-free
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian/ trixie main non-free-firmware contrib non-free

deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security trixie-security main non-free-firmware contrib non-free
deb-src http://security.debian.org/debian-security trixie-security main non-free-firmware contrib non-free

# trixie-updates, to get updates before a point release is made;
# see https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-reference/ch02.en.html#_updates_and_backports
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ trixie-updates main non-free-firmware contrib non-free
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian/ trixie-updates main non-free-firmware contrib non-free

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ bookworm main non-free-firmware contrib non-free
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian/ bookworm main non-free-firmware contrib non-free

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm main non-free-firmware
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian-security/ bookworm-security main non-free-firmware
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm-updates main non-free-firmware
```

Comment: Could you specify in more detail? The question seems a bit vague.

Comment: I updated my question, hopefully its more clear

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Stewart’s answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/766092/86440) points to [the “Don’t Break Debian” wiki page](https://wiki.debian.org/DontBreakDebian#Don.27t_make_a_FrankenDebian), which has good advice, but is written in a specific context which doesn’t quite apply in your case. The breakage mentioned there really refers to situations where the current stable release is the *main* release on the system, and packages are added from other (newer) releases.

In your case, since you’re tracking testing and missing packages, the advice given above doesn’t apply. For testing, [the usual advice *is* to mix releases](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianTesting#Best_practices_for_Testing_users) — testing and unstable (and possibly experimental). Doing *that* does require some care to avoid upgrading packages to unstable versions too early, so I wouldn’t recommend it for someone not all that familiar with the Debian development process. Mixing testing and the previous stable release is fine, and is better than rebuilding packages from stable on testing because in the latter case, upgrades won’t happen automatically.

ABI breakage shouldn’t be a concern because, at least for library ABIs, breakages are supposed to be avoided by using new package names. Thus two incompatible versions of a library can co-exist, and older packages using the older ABI won’t be affected by the new ABI. Of course, mistakes can happen, and discovering those early is part of what testing is for; so you might encounter problems, and you should be ready to deal with them yourself (*e.g.* by keeping track of bugs affecting your packages using `apt-listbugs`, putting packages on hold, etc.). Bear in mind that testing is the future stable release of Debian, and that means that the packages there need to support upgrades from Debian 12 — so anything which prevents them from working on a partially-upgraded Debian 12 system indicates a potential upgrade problem in the future, and should be addressed.

You don’t list specific packages you need from Debian 12 that aren’t available in testing, but it’s worth investigating why the packages aren’t available. Of course since Debian 12 is the currently-supported main stable release, the packages you use from Debian 12 are still maintained (in theory). However their removal from testing indicates that there’s something you should pay attention to. There are a few scenarios:

- the package is still in unstable, but not in testing because of a problem with the package or one of its dependencies — you might be able to help with that
- the package has been replaced by another — you should consider switching
- the package has been removed because it’s obsolete
- the package has been removed because it’s unmaintained
- the package has been removed because one or more of its dependencies are being removed

The last three are more annoying because there’s no simple long-term resolution; but unless they were removed because they are too buggy to use, packages removed because they are obsolete or because they rely on an obsolete dependency (*e.g.* `libappindicator1` in your case) are often safe to keep, as long as they remain available and maintained in the stable release you install them from.¹

You can find out the exact situation by looking for the package you’re interested in [on the Debian package tracker](https://tracker.debian.org/). When a package is removed, you’ll find links to the removal requests, and these should give you more information on the reasons behind the removal.

As far as maintaining `sources.list` goes, I would suggest not having a `sources.list` file at all, and instead maintaining “Deb822”-style repository configurations. In your case, this would mean a `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/bookworm.sources` file containing

```
Types: deb
URIs: http://deb.debian.org/debian
Suites: bookworm bookworm-updates
Components: main
Signed-By: /usr/share/keyrings/debian-archive-keyring.gpg

Types: deb
URIs: http://deb.debian.org/debian-security
Suites: bookworm-security
Components: main
Signed-By: /usr/share/keyrings/debian-archive-keyring.gpg
```

(with whatever “Components” entries you need), and another `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/trixie.sources` containing

```
Types: deb
URIs: http://deb.debian.org/debian
Suites: trixie trixie-updates
Components: main
Signed-By: /usr/share/keyrings/debian-archive-keyring.gpg

Types: deb
URIs: http://deb.debian.org/debian-security
Suites: trixie-security
Components: main
Signed-By: /usr/share/keyrings/debian-archive-keyring.gpg
```

---

¹ Unfortunately Debian doesn’t have a nice way of indicating that a package *should* be removed from a system when it is no longer maintained.

Comment: thank you very much for clarification, speacially for package traker, where I found missing package. 

In my edge case situation, where the latest Forticlient had unmet dependency in libappindicator1, removed from repository.

Answer (score 2):

Combining releases is a bad idea.  See [Don't make a FrankenDebian](https://wiki.debian.org/DontBreakDebian#Don.27t_make_a_FrankenDebian).

[Pinning](https://wiki.debian.org/AptConfiguration#apt_preferences_.28APT_pinning.29) is one solution, but can be volatile.  This lets you define priorities for specific packages for specific sources.  An example of where this breaks is if your package depends on a package that was upgraded in `trixie`, then you might have ABI incompatibilities and things will just crash.

I assume that you are not interested in a specific version, but in a package that was available in `bookworm` and was removed from `trixie`.  In that case, I would download the `bookworm` sources and build it in a `trixie` environment with `trixie` dependencies.

In that case, you'd only need this in your `/etc/apt/sources.list` (and that can be removed later)

```
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian/ bookworm main non-free-firmware contrib non-free
```

Then download the sources with:

```
apt update
apt source -t bookworm <package>
```

Then rebuild it with:

```
$ cd <package>_<version>
$ dpkg-buildpackage -uc -us
```

Then install it with:

```
sudo dpkg -i ../<package>*.deb
```

Then delete that `deb-src` line.  If the build fails, then you may need to [patch](https://wiki.debian.org/UsingQuilt) the sources.

Comment: Rebuilding from source means forgoing (automatic) updates from Debian 12 or even testing if the package is re-introduced there. Note that the FrankenDebian advice is written from the perspective of using the current stable release and adding packages from other (newer) releases to it; not using testing and adding older packages to it.